# errorformat: can't understand how to handle error for my parser

Tags: errorformat

I have a parser which output this kind of messages:

```
||     Error: M:\workdir\MyFile.ja: line 38: "Blablabla" has no license declaration
||     Error: M:\workdir\MyFile.ja: unknown attribute "blabla"
||     Fatal: M:\workdir\MyFile.ja: not generating output because of 2 earlier errors
```

I try to parse it with the following errorformat:

```
let &errorformat=&errorformat . ',' . 'Error: %f: line %l: %m'
let &errorformat=&errorformat . ',' . 'Error: %f: %m'
let &errorformat=&errorformat . ',' . 'Fatal: %f: line %l: %m'
let &errorformat=&errorformat . ',' . 'Fatal: %f: %m'
```

but it matches nothing. Can someone help me to points out what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Also posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44627902/660921

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in fact I needed to match also the leading spaces with this errorformat:

```
let &errorformat=&errorformat . ',' . '%*[ ]Error: %f: line %l: %m'
let &errorformat=&errorformat . ',' . '%*[ ]Error: %f: %m'
let &errorformat=&errorformat . ',' . '%*[ ]Fatal: %f: line %l: %m'
let &errorformat=&errorformat . ',' . '%*[ ]Fatal: %f: %m'
```

It works now like a charm !

Thanks to markzen on freenode #vim who helped me to find out the solution.